# .NET DataReader and ORDER BY

Tags: .net, sql, postgresql, ado.net

Is it normal behaviour for a DataReader to return the rows from a query out-of-order?

I'm fetching some rows from a PostgreSQL 8.3.7 database and am using ORDER BY, LIMIT and OFFSET as follows:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM tbl_foo
ORDER BY name
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

If I run this query manually the results are sorted and then the first ten rows are returned, which is what I would expect.

If I run the same query using a third-party ADO.NET provider for PostgreSQL (http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) the rows are not returned in the same order.  It could be an issue with the third-party provider, and I have a post on their forums asking about it.

I've tried loading the rows with DataTable.Fill() and have also looped through them with DataReader.Read().  In either case they aren't coming across in the correct order.

I thought I'd check here as well though and see if anyone has experienced the same behaviour with DataReaders in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came back to the problem with a fresh head this morning and as often happens the answer presented itself promptly.

Out of habit I was using Parameters to set the values of my ORDER BY, LIMIT and OFFSET in the query.  The later two work fine when set via parameters, but ORDER BY doesn't, probably because it's being turned into a string literal.

For interests sake I tested LIMIT and OFFSET and they will accept string literals instead of INTEGERs.

I guess I need to use string concatenation for the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like an issue with the provider, just make sure the columns you order by gives a determined result for the rows you are expecting e.g. a table with

```
id | Name
1  | John
2  | Peter
3  | John
```

And an order by on the Name column might not yield the same row order across queries. It could yield

```
1  | John        3  | John
3  | John    or  1  | John
2  | Peter       2  | Peter
```

Comment: I didn't specify in my question, but the named entities are divisions in a government ministry, so their names are always unique, but thank you for the example.

Answer (score 1):

The DataTable could do (through a View) some sorting on it's own but if the DataReader returns them out of order then there is definitely something wrong in the provider (or your query).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking to find out.  I'll wait on a reply from the vendor, then.

For what it's worth I don't want to do client-side sorting, as then I'd have to bring all the data back to the client as well, even if I'm only displaying ten rows.

In fact the application in question currently does do sorting & paging on in ASP with DataViews and I came across this issue while changing it to do it's paging and sorting on the database server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Postgres or the Devart drivers, but I can confirm that in SQL Server (2000 and up), if you do specify an `ORDER BY` (as you do), then these rows **will** be returned in that specified order by the SqlDataReader. I'm relying on that every day! :-)

Marc

Comment: Great, I didn't want to have to find an SQL Server installation to test against.  If it behaves that way with SqlClient than I can expect other providers should behave that way and file a bug with the vendor.